# Bibliography showing "and" instead of "&"

Tags: bibtex, natbib, harvard-style

I'm using `natbib` and the `apj` style file, and when the bibliography compiles it shows "and" in the author list (and in journal abbreviations) instead of "&". How do I change that so it shows "&"?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you post a Minimal Working Example showing what you are trying to do? I can't find `apj.bst` on ctan and it doesn't seem to have been in TeX Live 2011, 2012 or 2013 so I don't really have a clue what you're talking about. Do you expect `&`? Is that what the documentation says it will do? All the styles I've used use `and` but I'm sure some do things differently.

Answer (score 12):

that is hardcoded in the bst file, Copy it to `myapj.bst` and replace

```
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "and"}
```

with

```
FUNCTION {bbl.and}
{ "\&"}
```

and use in your document `\bibliographystyle{myapj.bst}`. The file `myapj.bst`
 can be saved in the documents directory or in your local bibtex/bst path, if available.

As an alternative use another harvard style like `apsr.bst` or `agsm.bst`, then you can write after loading `natbib`

```
\newcommand\harvardand{\&}
```

That bibstyles are part of TeXLive and MikTeX.

Comment: A minor typo, the command after loading `natbib` should be as follows to get the citations and bibliography to show **&** instead of **and**. `\newcommand\harvardand{\&}` @Herbert

Comment: you're right, because `natbib` uses `\AtBeginDocument` for the definition of `\harvardand`. The reason why it is not known in the preamble. I'll correct it.